# Azure Bot C# : Webchat Open url in same Tab of Browser, Its opening in new tab

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, bots, web-chat

Azure Bot C# :
1. Created one azure bot service and deployed on Azure.
2. I am using Webchat  into my web application to consume service.

Tried:
Already tried **HeroCard - CardAction** into bot to Open link.
I am able to open that link using **HeroCard - CardAction**, but requirement is to open that link into same tab Not in another new tab of browser.

Please help me on this if anyone knows about this.
Sharing C# code to create Herocard- CardAction to open URL.

```
heroCard = new HeroCard()
{
    Title = task.value1,
    Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
    {
        new CardAction()
        {
            Title = "Create New Task",
            Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
            Value = "http://localhost:11917/#/form/Tasks/-1/General"
        }                            
    }
};
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you done any research?

Comment: Yes tried postback and _blank URL options

Comment: Rohit, you are right. Downvotes are not for "I do not know". However, please consider whether the correct reason for downvoting "This question does not show any research effort;it is unclear or unhelpful." could possibly apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am able to open that link using HeroCard - CardAction, but requirement is to open that link into same tab Not in another new tab of browser.

To achieve your requirement, you can try to clone [the repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat), then modify the source code and compile into your own version.

In [AdaptiveCardContainer.tsx](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/9e85d31283615bbcd5b7025f6f60a2352a17369a/src/AdaptiveCardContainer.tsx#L101), we can find it opens new browser window using the following code:

```
if(action instanceof OpenUrlAction) {
    window.open(action.url);
}
```

We can modify the code to `window.open(action.url,"_self")`, then build changes and use our own version Web Chat in website.

***Test result:***

[image]

Comment: Please make sure you have npm installed, and then refer to my reply and follow steps of "[Building Web Chat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#building-web-chat)" to build your own version.